# Add Markers to folium map from SQLite3 table

Tags: python, sqlite, geocoding, folium

I am trying to drop many markers on a folium map. The coordinates are drawn from a SQLite3 Table but right now no map is displaying and no error is being thrown.

```
def maps():
    melbourne = (-37.840935, 144.946457)
    map = folium.Map(location = melbourne)
    
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('25july_database.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Connected to SQLite")

        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT latitude, longitude FROM test555;"""
        
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        
        items = cursor.fetchall()
        
        for item in items:
            folium.Marker(location = item)
            
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to read data from sqlite table", error)
    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("The SQLite connection is closed")
```

I tried to make "item" a list `folium.Marker(location = [item])` but that threw the following error `ValueError: Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, instead got: [(-37.7650309, 144.9613659)].`

This suggests to me that the variable is not wrong but something else is broken somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So get rid of the list. You already get a list of tuples back from the query. What's the error from `folium.Marker(location = item)`?

Comment: The error is from the list version. The code in the block above doesn’t throw an error but no map shows up and no markers either (as no map) I’m using Jupyter

Comment: I don't use folium but I use `leaflet` quite a lot. I strongly suspect that you're misdiagnosing this one because I often get the same issue. I'm pretty sure that wrapping it in a list is going in the wrong direction, though

Comment: Would you recommend leaflet over folium? I think wrapping it as a list is wrong as well. I just can’t figure out what else to try as there is no error otherwise

Comment: I can't recommend something when I haven't tried the alternative. But I can say that leaflet can bury errors and make it hard to debug. The only useful advice I could give was that the list approach is, in my view, incorrect. I'm sure that someone else can come clear up the issue for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extract the tuple `(-37.7650309, 144.9613659)` from the list, you just need to take the first element : `folium.Marker(location = item[0])`

You also need to add the marker to the map : `folium.Marker(location = item[0]).add_to(map)`

In order to draw the map, you need to return it at the end of your function.

You will have something like this (it works in my Jupyter Notebook) :

```
def maps():
    melbourne = (-37.840935, 144.946457)
    map = folium.Map(location = melbourne)
    
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('25july_database.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Connected to SQLite")

        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT latitude, longitude FROM test555;"""
        
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
        
        items = cursor.fetchall()
        
        for item in items:
            folium.Marker(location = item[0]).add_to(map)
            
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to read data from sqlite table", error)
    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("The SQLite connection is closed")
    return map
```

N.B:
You should not use `map` as the name of your variable because you shadow the `map()` function of the Python standard library.

Comment: Thanks so much, I also had to convert the "cursor.fetchall()" elements into a list before I did the part you suggested which worked!